# Typecasting to get Value from json object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a bit of trouble working something out with regards to javascript and Json.

I have a function that contains a json object

```
blah=function(i){
var hash= ({
  "foo" : "bar",
  "eggs":"bacon",
  "sausage":"maple syrup"
  });
var j=eval(hash); // Convert to Object
console.log(j.toSource()); // Yes I know it's only in firefox!
console.log(j.i); // Attempt to get the value of for example foo - which is bar
}
```

then call the function with `blah('foo');` to attempt it to console log "bar" form the json object.

THe trouble is all I get is "undefined" because the function is treating "i" as a string.

My quertion is how can I typecast the "i" variable to be soemthing that can access the json object.

Please help .. my head hurts and google has coem up short!.

Thanks in advance

Alex

Comment: Please accept an answer that you feel has helped you the most. You should do this because it provides valuable feedback to the answerers. You can do this by clicking the check mark next to the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

```
j[i]
```

:)

Comment: Unbelieveable .. I am such an idiot lol .. I had a feeling it would be something simple!